# Objective C NSMutable Array cannot add item

Tags: objective-c, object, interface, nsmutablearray, stack

Please take a look of my code 1st. I am trying to add some Car objects to a MutableArray *parkPlace (which a property belongs to Park class)

My expecting result should be showing as below:

```
CarParkSim[2662:303] Parking: Car Number:1 At:3 o'clok Position:0
CarParkSim[2662:303] Parking: Car Number:2 At:4 o'clok Position:1
CarParkSim[2662:303] Parking: Car Number:3 At:5 o'clok Position:2
```

However, the actualy result I got is like this:

```
2012-12-22 12:13:46.085 CarParkSim[2662:303] Parking: Car Number:1 At:3 o'clok Position:0
2012-12-22 12:13:46.087 CarParkSim[2662:303] Parking: Car Number:2 At:4 o'clok Position:0
2012-12-22 12:13:46.088 CarParkSim[2662:303] Parking: Car Number:3 At:5 o'clok Position:0
```

I did check the NSmutablearray, it is empty...it dosent seem to push anything to the stack...
any suggestions? thanks

anyway, here is the code:
Park class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Stack.h"
#import "Car.h"

@interface Park : NSObject
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *parkPlace;
@property(strong,nonatomic)Car *car;
-(void)carMoveIntoPark:(Car *)car;
@end

#import "Park.h"
@implementation Park

-(void)carMoveIntoPark:(Car *)car
{

if ([self.parkPlace count] <= 2) {

    Car *car1 = [[Car alloc] init];
    car1.carNumber = 1;
    car1.timeIO = 3;

    [self.parkPlace push:car1];
    int carNumber = car.carNumber;
    int carTimer = car.timeIO;
    NSUInteger parkPosition = [self.parkPlace count];
    NSLog(@"Parking: Car Number:%d At:%d o'clok Position:%ld", carNumber, carTimer, parkPosition);

} else {
    //to be implement later
} 
}
 @end
```

and here is my Main:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
Car *car1 = [[Car alloc] init];
car1.carNumber = 1;
car1.timeIO = 3;

Car *car2 = [[Car alloc] init];
car2.carNumber = 2;
car2.timeIO = 4;

Car *car3 = [[Car alloc] init];
car3.carNumber = 3;
car3.timeIO = 5;

Park *park = [[Park alloc] init];
[park carMoveIntoPark:car1];
[park carMoveIntoPark:car2];
[park carMoveIntoPark:car3];
```

and this is my Car class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Car : NSObject
@property(assign,nonatomic)int carNumber;
@property(assign,nonatomic)int timeIO;

@end


#import "Car.h"
@implementation Car
@end
```

By the way, I m trying to use stack data structure to push cars on to a 'stack', since there is no such data structure in objective c, so i have implemented my own, here is the stack class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSMutableArray (Stack)
-(void) push:(id)item;
-(id)pop;
-(id)peek;
-(void)replaceTop:(id)item;

@end


#import "Stack.h"

@implementation NSMutableArray (Stack)

-(void)push: (id)item{
[self addObject:item];
}

-(id)pop {
id item = nil;
if ([self count] != 0) {
    item = [self lastObject];
    [self removeLastObject];
}
return item;
}

-(id)peek{
id item = nil;
if([self count] != 0) {
    item= [self lastObject];
}
return item;
}

-(void) replaceTop:(id)item{
if([self count] == 0) {
    [self addObject:item];
}else{
    [self removeLastObject];
    [self addObject:item];
}
}

@end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't allocate memory anywhere for your array. That's what constructors have been invented for:

```
@implementation Park

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        parkPlace = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    // The destructor needs to be implemented as well
    [parkPlace release];
    [super dealloc];
}

// Other parts of the implementation here

@end
```

Comment: You could improve your example a bit by using instance variables instead of property references in `init` and `dealloc`. From [The Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW1): *The only places you shouldn’t use accessor methods to set an instance variable are in initializer methods and `dealloc`.*

Comment: @jlehr Well, that's something that can be argued upon. It's better not to use instance variables directly because their *exact* memory management internals are an implementation detail.

Comment: Instance variables don't have `memory management internals,` so I'm not really sure what you mean by that, but in any case you might want to give some more thought to the merits of advising developers to do things that Apple's documentation clearly states they shouldn't do.

Comment: The reason is that accessors can, and often do, have side-effects, and the state of an object that's partially initialized or destroyed is indeterminate. Therefore, side-effects could lead to potential runtime errors. While these kinds of problems tend to be rare, they can be difficult to reproduce and to debug if and when they crop up.

Answer (score 3):

You've not initialised parkPlace - it's still nil. Objective-C lets you send messages to nil by default but they don't do anything.

If I were you I'd be setting that up in the init method of your Park class.